# How to use Libre Office page field in the Velocity condition

Tags: java, velocity, libreoffice, odt, xdocreport

I use XDOCREPORT and create .odt template with use Velocity.

I need to add condition

```
#if($libre_office_count_pages > 1)
    VOID
#else 
    $mayValue
#end
```

but I can't find how I can insert standart **Page Count Field** in the **Input Field**

If I write part #if( as InputField and insert Page Count Filed and in the end == 1) as InputField. I has error.